# i want to save a image with out user interaction in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I m scanning image in a form i want to save the image with out user interaction in C# can any one help..

```
string chktemp = @"C:\"+pic+".tif";
  Bitmap bm= new Bitmap(from file);//Here it is asking already saved file with out this i want to save just now scanned image from form
 bm.Save(chktemp);
```

Comment: I have tried the code and it was not asking for any confirmation, Note: Saving the image to the same file it was constructed from is not allowed and throws an exception. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use IO to check if the current file exists, and if so delete it first.
See: System.IO documentation

File.Exists
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx

File.Delete
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx

Comment: If i m deleting the image then Argument exception was unhand-led error coming.. parameter is not valid it is saying

Comment: Delete throws exceptions, so you need to wrap your Delete call in a try/catch block to handle the case of exception. The easiest method is to do nothing in the catch. Ie, `try { System.IO.Delete(path); } catch (Exception e) { }`

Comment: i modified as you said... but it showing same error as parameter is not valid,

Comment: my main task is scanning image and need to save it with out user interaction automatically any where in a folder.

Comment: the image is scanned but unable to save same with out user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Load the Image File to Stream ,than you can Create Bitmap from Stream ,which will close the File Read Operation in source Image .